# Can a Mac with Boot Camp support multiple Windows?

Tags: windows-7, mac, multi-boot

Can a Mac with [Boot Camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29) support multiple Windows? Such as Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 7 64 bit all on the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you boot up you will be presented with multiple "boot" disks to choose from.

Good general [information about bootcamp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461).

Good [writeup about multiple partitions](http://newartisans.com/2007/10/install-bootcamp-with-multiple-partitions/).